# Div Vertical Scroll

Tags: css, html

So I recently updated a site for a client of mine, who wanted to keep it very simple.. Normally I have designed sites so they are a specific width and then center horizontally on the page. Due to the gallery they requested, I made the site 100% with a min-width of 960px and max-height of 576px. For the most part her text content is limited, so there are only a few pages which result in a vertical scroll in the Div when the overall width of the page hits 960px. The Div box uses the overflow-x: auto; command. This works well on all of the pages except one..

For example the following page looks great at 100% and when the window width is changed to where the text needs to scroll, the scroll bar is on the far right: http://www.lisagleeson.com/about/

I am having a small problem with the following page: http://www.lisagleeson.com/resume/

This pages content is setup to split the content into 2 columns.. Ideally it would be great for it to be 3 when the screen is wide enough, but when smaller have it revert to 2 columns.. So far I have it setup with 2 columns and it looks fine, the only problem I notice is with the vertical scrollbar. Rather then the scroll bar being on the far right, it's just past the 2 column. Is there a way to fix this where the scrollbar is on the far right?

Here is the CSS I am using, Content is the main Div, textContent sits within that one and then  Resume sits within that one.

Thanks in advance for the help...

```
#content {
width: 100%;
min-width: 960px;
height: 576px;
margin-top:20px;
position: absolute;
background-color: #ffffff;
display: none;
}

#textContent {
min-width: 400px;
height: 515px;
float: left;
margin: -525px 20px 10px 520px;
padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
overflow-x: auto;
}

#resume {

-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;

-moz-column-gap:40px;
-webkit-column-gap:40px;
column-gap:40px;

-moz-column-rule: 1px outset #eeeeee; 
-webkit-column-rule: 1px outset #eeeeee; 
column-rule: 1px outset #eeeeee; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll bar should show on the far right of the div that requires scrolling.

If you increase the width of #textContent then the scrollbar will move further right. The trouble with setting it to a static pixel size is that for people with smaller screens it could be pushed off the edge of the page.

Try setting #textContent to `width:100%` and see if that helps you.

Comment: changed the #textContent to width:100% but it pushed everything to the right and the column widths were smaller..

Comment: Hmm. That means something else is getting in the way of the normal layout. Could you set up a bare bones version on jsfiddle.net to try and isolate the problems?